# (Android) Layout won't redraw after setVisibility(view.GONE)?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

In app I have:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cvLinearLayout2);
```

and **after**:

```
linearLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**I can't find a way to bring `linearLayout2` back.**

Tried everything:

```
  linearLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  linearLayout2.bringToFront();
  linearLayout2.getParent().requestLayout();
  linearLayout2.forceLayout();
  linearLayout2.requestLayout();
  linearLayout2.invalidate();
```

but with no results.
`linearLayout2` have one parent `linearLayout1`, so I tried also:

```
  linearLayout1.requestLayout();
  linearLayout1.invalidate();
```

still with zero results. `linearLayout2` stays `GONE`.
In my app I need to move `linearLayout` away, and then, after a while to redraw it again. Please help.

Comment: try not setting the visibility to GONE in first place and tell whether the layout appears now.

Comment: this cant happen UNTIL and UNLESS you are not doing something wrong in between the time you make it gone and visible. 

Just check if you are removing/deleting any view contained by your linearLayout2. Post some of your code snippets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting a View's visibility to GONE should not affect it's ability to "come back" by using the method setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

For example I have this code in one of my apps:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton checkBox, boolean isChecked{
    if(checkBox == usesLocationCheckBox)
    {
        View view = findViewById(R.id.eventLocationOptions);
        if(isChecked)
        {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            usesTimeCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
        }
        if(!isChecked)
        {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            usesTimeCheckBox.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }}
```

And it works perfectly fine.  Some other code your program is executing must be responsible.  Edit your post with the relevant code, and we may be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: huh..code is too large :-( 

setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) not working.

but its simple : **I need fullscreen feature.**


In onCreate() linearlayout2 is created, then after touch event (but ACTION_UP) I need fullscreen so I need to "remove" linearlayout 2 (used view.GONE), then after some time I need it back, and I cant do it anyhow :-(

view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) is not good for me, couse view still occupies space.. i need something like .removeView() but that is complicated...

hope I managed to explain... 

I need fullscreen feature..remove View then get it back with data

Comment: Can you post your code here, so I can get a better idea of how to help you?  I might be able to figure out why View.VISIBLE isn't working.

Comment: Guys its just started to work !!! After 2 days.. I just removed all except view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

and 
 view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
and whole thing works, so Garzahd U R right, it must to work :-)
Thanks !!

Answer (score 7):

`View.GONE` will remove the View from the screen, and the space occupied by the View is released to other Views on screen. So, a "GONE" view cannot come back. You need to reload it.

If you want to keep the space, you can use `View.INVISIBLE`. Now the View is NOT removed, instead, it hides the View and display blank space.

In simple illustration, you have the following setup:

`ABCD`

After calling `B.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` you will have:

`A CD`

But after calling `B.setVisibility(View.GONE);` you will get:

`ACD`

Comment: tnx, but I need that released space, so INVISIBLE still keep "space" , i need to move away linearlayout and after some time get it back.
To be more specific, It is Full screen feature, so I need whole screen for some time, and after some time get linearlayout2 back :-)

Comment: After `GONE` you can load it again like `LinearLayout linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cvLinearLayout2);` and YourActivity.setLayout(linearLayout2);`

Comment: There is no such method.
YourActivity.setLayout(linearLayout2);

Comment: Correct, it should be `setContentView(linearLayout2)`, thanks for pointing it.

Comment: How to recreate child layout without reload full layout?